# SQLite indexing groups of rows?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a large set of city, state pairs I'm loading into a SQLite table. I will be querying the city and will know the state. Suppose I want to look for a particular city that I know is in Texas. The following query is roughly O(n) notwithstanding the limit, right?

```
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE state_abbr=? LIMIT 1
```

Is there some way of grouping the rows by state or creating a secondary index or something so that SQLite knows where to the find the 'TX' rows and only search within them? I've considered creating separate tables for each state-- and that's an option-- but I'm hoping I can just do something within this single table to make the queries more efficient.

In the tutorials I've read, the query doesn't change after creating a composite index. Is SQLite just using the index under the hood on the same query?

Comment: Start with reading https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html

Comment: and you must try and test , and use `explain query plan select * from .... ; ` to see wich index sqlite is using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just have a composite index?

```
create index cities_state_abbr_city on cities(state, city);
```

Comment: Sure? I've been reading tutorials on indices all morning and none of them explain clearly what actually happens when you create a composite index or how it makes querying more efficient, so I'm having a hard time figuring out whether it solves this problem or not.

Comment: @AutomaticStatic . . . If you have queries that are on `state` or have an equality condition on `state` and any condition on `city`, then this is the appropriate index.  I find that MySQL has pretty good documentation on multi-column indexes:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html.